# How to update .NETStandard in VS 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-standard, tweetsharp

When installing TweetSharp I get this error message:

```
Install-Package : Package TweetSharp 2.3.1 is not compatible with netstandard1.4 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.4). Package TweetSharp 2.3.1 supports:
  - net20 (.NETFramework,Version=v2.0)
  - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - sl4 (Silverlight,Version=v4.0)
  - sl4-wp (Silverlight,Version=v4.0,Profile=WindowsPhone)
  - sl4-wp71 (Silverlight,Version=v4.0,Profile=WindowsPhone71)
```

I have tried updating .NETStandard to the most recent release being 2.0 but that doesn't work.

I have also tried using the command 'nuget.exe locals -clear all' that also doesn't work.

How can I update netstandard1.4 to one supported by TweetSharp?

Thank you.

Comment: I went into properties of the project and I can only target the 1.6 .NET framework and no higher even though they are included with VS 2017 as I discovered when trying to download and install higher versions of the framework. Furthermore under the .NETStandardLibrary when managing nuget packages it says in the dependencies that the .NET Framework is 4.6 which should be enough to install TweetSharp.

Comment: Did you install the .net core 2.0.0 sdk and removed any global.json pinning a lower sdk version?

Comment: Installing the .net core 2.0.0 sdk fixed it thank you!